# Objective-C OpenGL game tutorials

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es

I would like to start making an iPhone/Ipod game with xCode 4.2 I have registered with apple and have everything I need but information. I know just a little Objective-C and need a tutorial that will explain **everything** because I do not get a bunch of the code like why they put it there and why it has to be a capital letter or why a space is there. This tutorial needs to also have the OpenGL related content.

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start is with lectures from Stanford which are available on iTunesU. Search for iPhone Development by Paul Heagarty

Comment: Thanks this looks like a great tutorial after watching the first tutorial.